# Redis set operations

Tags: redis

Redis Set Operation:

SADD key1 "value1 containing key1"

SADD key1 "value2 containing key1"

SADD key1 "value3 containing key1"

SMEMBERS 
Result :
1) "value2 containing key1"
2) "value3 containing key1"
3) "value1 containing key1"

SREM key1 "value2 containing key1" --> it works

Now i want to delete "value2 containing key1" from set, without passing whole value e.g. "value2 containing key1". Want to send only "value2"

SREM key1 "value2"

is there any way to do this ? Or any other method?

Comment: What you are asking doesn't really make any sense. What exactly are you trying to do? It sounds like you might want to look at a hash map instead.

Comment: you can modify the source code of Redis and make it again

Comment: @kaitian can you please guide me for same?

Comment: Inside Redis, it uses skipList to store set elements, BUT it MUST compare two elements when you insert or query a element.  What's more,  what you want to implement is somewhat not neccessary. what can you earn from  "value2" instead of ""value2 containing key1" ?

Comment: @kaitian my requirement is something like i will pass some value, based on that, will delete value from set.

sadd key1 "value1 : message" 

now during delete i want to pass only value1 as parameter to SREM

SREM key1 "value1"     not "value1 : message"

here message is long string.
is there any other way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of inserting into SET the full value("value1 : verylongmessage"), you can just inserting value("value1") to the set "key1".

BUT you should use another data structure, Hash to store the full content of the value1:

```
hash['value1'] = "value1 : verylongmessage" (in Redis, you can use HSET?)
```

So, if you want to delete value1 from the SET, you just delete from both the SET and the HASH.

Hope this can help you ~~~